# TypeError: this.buf.utf8Write is not a function

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I am trying to create a facade for the npm library [avsc](https://github.com/mtth/avsc). When I compile with `sbt fastOptJS::webpack` and open the .html file, I get `TypeError: this.buf.utf8Write is not a function` from the line `this.buf.utf8Write(s, pos, len);` in [that](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L538) file of the js library. It is called from the `toBuffer` function.

My code using the facade should work:

```
val schema = """{"type" : "record", "name": "Pet", "fields": [{"name": "name", "type": "string"}]}"""
val petType = avro.parse(schema)
val jsDict = js.Dictionary("name" -> "Tom")
println(petType.isValid(jsDict)) // prints 'true'
val buf = petType.toBuffer(jsDict)
```

Also have a look at the whole [project](https://github.com/Tamriel/treepad/blob/master/src/main/scala/avsc/avsc.scala), it's very little code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: When avsc is used on the client side with webpack or browserify, one has to use require('avsc/etc/browser/avsc').